# Hibernate order by DiscriminatorColumn using AuditQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to get records from the DB, order by DiscriminatorColumn.
The thing is, I need to use AuditQuery, not the HQL.

In HQL I could use **(...) order by e.class**.
But how to that that using AuditQuery?

Comment: You can add an answer to your own question and then later mark it as the correct answer. It's better that way since it wont show as unanswered and your solution might assist others in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like solution was quiet simple, nevertheless I havent't found it anywhere, it was just a lucky shot.

```
query.addOrder(AuditEntity.property("class").asc())
```

In case someone will find it useful